# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.math' has no attribute 'is_inf'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, onnx

I want to use ONNX to exchange models from ONNX to Tensorflow however I get an error.
I searched in similar cases to resolve this issue but could not find an answer to solve this problem.
The error message is :

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.math' has no attribute 'is_inf'

I have created an anaconda environment as follows:

```
conda create -n <env> python=3.6 tensorflow==1.13 
conda install -n <env> -c conda-forge onnx-tf
```

In order to reproduce the error do the following:

1. Activate the anaconda environment
2. run python
3. "import tensorflow as tf"
4. "import onnx"
5. "from onnx_tf.backend import prepare"

This will result in the error :

I have tried the same with an environment running tensorflow 1.9.0 too. This has the same problem

Any idea's what is the root casue and how to solve this?

Thanks for the support

Comment: I have just checked on TensorFlow 1.13.1 and `tf.math.is_inf` is there (but it is not in 1.12.0). Maybe try with `conda create -n <env> python=3.6 tensorflow==1.13.1` and see if it works?

Comment: I created a new conda environment with tensorflow 1.13.1.Now it seems to work properly. thanks for the quick reply